# How to organize the flow of data in Flink when tables can't be partitioned using the same identifier

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm convinced that Flink is the perfect solution to my event processing problem. I have even managed to produce a working prototype, but I'm not convinced it is even close to optimal.

Here is my scenario:

- I have two kinesis streams

  - One stream contains `Event1` and is stored as `JSON`
  - The other stream contains `Event2`, `Event3`, and `Event4` but is stored as Gzip'd Base64 (which ultimately is also `JSON`). I have to process this using the `RAW` format and then extract the event data using a custom UDF `process_events234` - created by implementing `TableFunction[Row]` in a Scala class.
- I want to detect when 4 corresponding events have arrived, but there is no single value I can use to join all 4 data types the events represent. See below:

| Data Type | Has key1 | Has key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Event1 | Yes | No |
| Event2 | Yes | Yes |
| Event3 | No | Yes |
| Event4 | No | Yes |

My prototype notebook has the following:

### Define a table for event_1s

```sql
CREATE TABLE event_1 (
  key1,
  ...
)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'kinesis',
    'stream' = 'stream_of_event_1s',
    ...
    'format' = 'json'
)
```

### Define a table for event_1,2,3s

```sql
CREATE TABLE events_234 (
  Data BYTES
)
WITH (
    'connector' = 'kinesis',
    'stream' = 'stream_of_event_1_2_3s',
    ...
    'format' = 'raw'
)
```

### Create a view to separate each event 2,3,4

```sql
CREATE VIEW event_N // Where N is 2,3,4
AS
SELECT 
      p.*
FROM
      events_234 e
      JOIN LATERAL table(process_events234(e.Data)) as p ON TRUE
WHERE
      p.eventType = 'eventN' // Where N is 2,3,4
```

### Join the data together to get my results

```sql
/*INSERT INTO my_downstream_sink */
SELECT
    e1.*, e2.*, e3.*, e4.*
FROM
    event_1 e1
    INNER JOIN event_2 e2 ON e1.key1 = e2.key1
    INNER JOIN event_3 e3 ON e2.key2 = e3.key2
    INNER JOIN event_4 e4 ON e2.key2 = e4.key2
```

My current prototype is working for a few hundred records over a 10 minutes period, but I doubt it's ability to scale. What concerns me is the fact that I am not able to `partition`/`keyBy` the data such that I imagine it would exist on the same worker. I'm new to Flink, but this seem particularly important.

What occurs to me is to expand the number of steps and kinesis streams such that:

- I join Event1 and Event2 then insert that onto a new stream `Event1+Event2` partitioned by `key2`
- Then join `Event1+Event2` with `Event3`, `Event4`

However, I'm just guessing and would appreciate some expert advice and opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry; Flink's SQL planner/optimizer should handle this just fine.

You may find it useful to use EXPLAIN and/or look at the resulting job graph in the Flink web dashboard to get a clearer idea of how the query is being executed. I believe you'll find that it's doing exactly what you propose (creating an `Event1+Event2` stream, keying it by `key2`, and then joining with the other streams) without the expense of writing the `Event1+Event2` stream out to Kinesis and reading it in again.